# Error when including git.exe in a Pyinstaller app to be used by clients

Tags: python, git, windows-10, pyinstaller

I'm designing a GUI application that will be distributed to others, written with Python, that includes the use of Kivy and GitPython.

I'm running into major issues when trying to package the program with Pyinstaller.

This is a sample of my python script where I'm defining the path to the the git exe in the 'dist' folder created by Pyinstaller.

```
base_path = os.getcwd()
splitString = base_path.split('\\')
if 'dist' in splitString:
    end_index = splitString.index('dist')
    splitString = splitString[:end_index]
    save_path = ''
    for string in splitString:
        save_path += string + '\\'
    save_path = save_path[:-1]
    # Establish path to git.exe
    git_path = base_path + '\\git\\'
    cmd = f'SET PATH=%PATH%;{git_path}'
    os.system(cmd)

import git
```

And this is a sample of my spec file generated by Pyinstaller.

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[path\to\main.py],
             binaries=[('C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe', '.\\git')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['win32timezone'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='sample_app',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True)
```

I'm getting this error over and over again when trying to `import git`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 162, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\<name>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pyinstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    File "site-packages\git\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
        manage the module state. Use the 'ctx' variable dictionary. This
ImportError: Failed to initialize: Bad git executable. 
The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:
    - be included in your $PATH
    - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
    - explicitly set via git.refresh()

All git commands will error until this is rectified.

This initial warning can be silenced or aggravated in the future by setting the
$GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH environment variable. Use one of the following values:
    - quiet|q|silence|s|none|n|0: for no warning or exception
    - warn|w|warning|1: for a printed warning
    - error|e|raise|r|2: for a raised exception

Example:
    export GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet
```

When I run the exe on my personal computer (which has git installed here `C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe` ) everything runs totally normally. It's just went the exe is run on a computer that DOES NOT have git installed where it throws the error shown above.

It should be able to work since I'm including git as a binary file to Pyinstaller but it's just not working for me right now.

I've tried all of the suggestions made in the error message and nothing is working. Not sure if I'm missing a hidden import or something but I'm completely stumped so any assistance would be appreciated!!

Comment: The Git suite of programs is more than just `git.exe`; installing only the `.exe` file is not sufficient and won't get you a working Git. Don't try to have your own program install Git, just list Git as a requirement if you intend to use it.

Comment: https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Appendix-B%3A-Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-Dulwich , https://pypi.org/project/dulwich/